# Stack Exchange in Google Search

Tags: discussion

How did Stack Exchange all of a sudden start appearing in all of my Google searches? And how does a question such as this one not meet quality standards?

Comment: Your question does not meet the standard because a single sentence does not explain your request properly. What does *start appearing in all of my google searches* actually mean?

Comment: to increase the quality of your question, include some links to searches that get unexpected SE results, and explain why they're unexpected.

Comment: I see it was edited, seriously?

Comment: Yes, seriously. It's Stack Exchange, not StackExchange.

Comment: It was edited from the original way i submitted it. As if to show a quality problem, when in fact it was a question short in length.

Answer (score 2):

It's "Stack Exchange". Two words.

...and "standands" should be "standards".

...and also, what is your question?

Comment: Shog9, as the Community Manager: is there any official position about using a `&nbsp;` non-breaking space in names like Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Arjan You noticed as well... never understood the point of that.

Comment: Yup, @Bart, and I know both of us have asked that user about that. ;-) (It actually annoys me if the combined `Stack&nbsp;Overflow` [does not fit on a line](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AnV4Y.png), while just `Stack` would fit nicely. Especially on mobile where lines are short on my devices... But well, nothing to lose any sleep on!)